# Upload two similar applications to Android Market

Tags: android

I want to upload the same application twice to the Android Market. One version will have AdMob messages and the other version of the same app will cost a pair of bucks.

Should I make two applications with differents packages names in order to upload them or is there any trick to do it with the same project.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every application at Android Market must have unique package name, so you have to place your apps into different packages (one be a subpackage of another though, i.e. com.app and com.app.ads). You can share common code in a library project.

Answer (score 0):

You will need two different package names. You might also consider to exclude certain parts of your code in your free version, because Android Market is known for not being the most secure distribution channel. But if the only difference is the additional ads in your free version, it is not worth the effort.

Answer (score 0):

There is another possibility, which unfortunately, I don't know how to do, but I'd like to find out.  You can put all the functionality into one app and then create a second app which acts as a "key".  Users download your first app for free, but it has limited functionality unless the "key" app is also present.  You would charge users to download the "key" app.

This solution has the advantage of not having to maintain two code bases for every app, which is what I do and it drives me nuts.